# Why is it not possible to set ctrl + tab as keyboard shortcut on mac os x and Textmate?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I switched to Textmate and want to switch tabs with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (like in NetBeans).

The menu command is Navigation - Next File Tab. But it's not possible to set any shortcut with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key? Is this a general limitation?

Comment: Your question's title says you want to use Ctrl-Tab, but your question's text says Cmd-Tab.  While I haven't tried Cmd-Tab, I have got this to work for Ctrl-Tab on Yosemite OS X with TextMate 2.0-beta.6. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is sacred in textmate :-)

It's the trigger for the snippet engine so ... <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + arrow keys will toggle through the tabs. Also, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + (<kbd>1</kbd> till <kbd>9</kbd>) will jump to a tab.

Answer (score 1):

Use Spark to set up a Textmate-specific Text/Keyboard Hotkey which sends the Cmd + Opt + Arrow

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't be able to bind <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to anything, as it is used by the operating system, but you should be able to bind <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> — like Safari does. It may be a limitation of TextMate.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-Tab (and Ctrl-Shift-Tab) can be used to switch tabs in TextMate (I'm currently running TextMate v2.0-beta.6 on OS X Yosemite).

To setup

1. go to OS X System Preferences, then Keyboard, then Shortcuts, and then Application Shortcuts.
2. Click the "+" button to add a new one.  Select TextMate as the application, then enter "Select Next Tab" with `ctrl-tab` as the Keyboard Shortcut.
3. Repeat this with "Select Previous Tab" and `shift-ctrl-tab` to get the previous tab shortcut working.

Comment: This did not work for me in TextMate 2.0-beta.7.4 in Yosemite

Answer (score 0):

Use [Accessibility Options](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202562) to disable keyboard controls.

Doing that this helped me cycle through tabs again.